# Does connecting slower Powerline adaptor to 1gbit powerline slow the network down

Tags: networking, powerline-networking

I have 1gbit Powerline network. If I plug in 200mbit PL adapter, will it degrade speed between devices connected to my old 1Gbit adapters?